# Multiple Servlets in WebApplicationInitializer

Tags: java, spring, servlets

I was trying to set up multiple servlets in my `WebApplicationInitializer`, one for the default requests (that trigger the jsp and return the html, using a `DispatcherServlet`, and one for static resources, using a custom made `StaticServlet`. What confuses me is how to apply the routing to get the requests to the right servlet, and in fact one of the static servlet is never called to resolve the requests seems to confirm my suspicions. So far this is the code I have on the `WebApplicationInitializer`:

```
@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
    servletContext.setSessionTrackingModes(
        Collections.<SessionTrackingMode>emptySet());

    // Create the 'root' Spring application context
    // which will contain the application components
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext
        = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    rootContext.register(RootConfig.class);

    // Manage the lifecycle of the root application context
    servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));

    // Create the dispatcher servlet's Spring application context
    // to contain dispatched beans such as controllers
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext dispatcherContext
        = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    dispatcherContext.register(DispatcherConfig.class);

    // Register and map the dispatcher servlet under /
    ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet(
        "dispatcher",
        new DispatcherServlet(dispatcherContext));
    dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    dispatcher.addMapping("/");
    
    // Register and map the static dispatcher servlet under /static/*
    ServletRegistration.Dynamic staticDispatcher = servletContext.addServlet(
        "staticDispatcher",
        new FileServlet());

    staticDispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    staticDispatcher.setInitParameter("basePath", "/static/fonts/");
    staticDispatcher.addMapping("/static/*");
```

The static `Servlet` do not need a `Configuration` (Is a base `HttpServlet`), but what bothers me is the fact that I am using two `ServletRegistration` in order to define the two different mappings. Is there a way to use the same one and define the mapping to a specific servlet? Or should the mapping be done at another level (maybe the Listener of the `rootContext`)? I have tried to look around but it seems no one has solved or have any problem (probably) to set up multiple servlets programmatically.

Any idea of why I'm not getting any hit on the static `Servlet`?

### Edit:

This is a static file request in one of my .jsp files, that would be supposed to go through the `FileServlet`:

```
<style type="text/css">
     @font-face {
        font-family: 'DinWeb';
        src: url(/static/fonts/DINWeb.eot?) format('eot'), url(/static/fonts/DINWeb.woff)  format('woff'), url(/static/fonts/DINComp.ttf) format('truetype');
        font-weight: normal;
    }
</style>
```

What I would expect is the request to be redirected to the `FileServlet` (since the url starts with /static/), and from there be manipulated/managed so that it would return the font (or a file or another media)

Comment: Why are you using this `FileServlet` instead of using the resource handler provided by the `DispatcherServlet`?

Comment: My main problem is that the 'DispatcherServlet' is already used by another infrastructure build upon spring, so I am already using a predefined 'DispatcherConfig' for the 'Serlvet' (I don't even have @Controller available for example). Do you have any tips on how to set the right routing to from the servlet to a resource handler?

Comment: Please give us examples (edit your question) of the URL requests you make and what you expect the result to be.

Comment: I don't know css very well, but it seems like you haven't provided a context path. What happens when you put that path directly into the browser?

Comment: I get a HTTP Status 404, type: Status report, description: The requested resource is not available. What bugs me is that even with css requests, is not that I handle the requests erroneously, but it just seems to ignore my mapping to /static altogheter

Comment: Do you have a context path like `localhost:8080/yourapp/static/some/resource.css`?

Comment: Hi Sotirious, that might be the problem. After I deploy my code, in my ROOT/WEB-INF folder I have all the resources, but no folder for the static files (which are currently stored in a parent folder. I will try to work on that. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Founded an alternative Solution: Instead of making two `DispactherServlet` (or one and another), just implement a servlet and a `Filter` that will listen to all requests, and take care of those URLs that starts with static.

In my code I added this two lines:

```
FilterRegistration filterReg = servletContext.addFilter("staticFilter",     StaticFilesFilter.class);
filterReg.addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, false, "/*");
```

and removed completely the second custom made servlet. As per the filter, this [link](https://sites.google.com/site/slugfiller/staticfilter) is pretty useful (Just click the download to see the java file of the filter implementation itself).